# iPhone autorotation for too many objects on screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, autorotate

I have a BlahAppDelegate, BlahViewController and no nibs in my iPhone app project. Only some subclasses of UIView in addition. All this is situated in main.m.
My app has 6 subclassed UIViews. Each of it contains 18 UIImageViews.

I need to get autorotating work. Or custom rotating. Or something. For example it would be nice to fade the screen out when device is rotated, then move/resize views and then fade screen out. But I don't know how to automate it, without writing a resizing code for each of objects.

Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to use the autoresizingMask property of your image views. These act just like the springs-and-struts in IB. If you position your views relative to their parents, and set these appropriately, you should have no problems. However, your options are somewhat limited; basically fixed distance from the edge, or proportionally spaced. No child-relative alignment is possible using just the flags.

Comment: I don't use IB in my project, or I just misunderstood your comment. Can you give some code on how to implement that please?

Comment: the autoresizingMask (thanks Noah!) is a complex beast. You're definitely going to want to read the doc on it. It might also help to play with IB's springs-and-struts (that's the resizing section) to get a feel for how they affect your view bounds. Basically, using an OR'd combination of the auto-resizing flags, you can make your width and height shrink or grow with the parent.

Comment: For example, to make your child view stay centered horizontally in its parent, and maintain its width, even as you change the parent's bounds, set its autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin.